# How to advance through data from the std::io::Read trait when Seek isn't implemented?

Tags: io, rust

What's the best way to read from a type implementing the `std::io::Read` trait when the contents of the output isn't important?

Possible options I see are:

- Read single bytes in a loop.
- Allocate a *potentially huge* vector and read into that.
- Something in-between... *read into a fixed sized buffer in a loop*.

The first 2 options don't seem ideal, the third is OK but inconvenient.

Does Rust provide a convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`io::copy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html), [`Read::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) and [`io::sink()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.sink.html) to discard a specific number of bytes:

```
let mut file = File::open("foo.txt").unwrap();

// Discard 27 bytes
io::copy(&mut file.by_ref().take(27), &mut io::sink());

// Read the rest
let mut interesting_contents = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut interesting_contents).unwrap();
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7d256161e326480085170407417499d9&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Here, we also have to use [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) in order to be able to still use the file afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (`dyn Read`). After `io::copy(..)`, the result from `read(..)` is still in same as reading before `io::copy(..)`. Why?