# How can I skip a number of bytes from a data source that implements the Read trait without a buffer?

Tags: io, rust

I'm writing a streaming binary encoding parser, pulling bytes from a data source that implements the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait. Values in the stream are prefixed with a short header that indicates what type the next value is and how many bytes it takes to represent it.

I've been using [`Read::bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.bytes) to read the header. Then, if I'm interested in the value that the header represents, I can use the [`Read::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) method to copy the required number of bytes from the data source into a buffer. However, if I'm *not* interested in the value, I'd like to skip over those bytes without having to process them. I can achieve this by doing:

```
for byte_result in data_source.bytes().take(n) {
    let _byte = byte_result?;
}
```

However, checking on the result of each individual byte feels very expensive. Is there a way I can achieve this that only requires that I check the result of an overall `skip` operation?

The [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html) trait is promising, but many forms of input do not implement it ([`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html), for example.)

Comment: `lseek` is not supported on sockets by POSIX. This is likely because there wouldn't be a real benefit compared to just reading and discarding, and is likely why the `Seek` trait is not implemented on `TcpStream`. You are right that reading byte by byte and using `?` seems expensive. However, `read_exact` might be more efficient (but has the downside to require a buffer of the right size).

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to advance through data from the std::io::Read trait when Seek isn't implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42243355/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Yep, that answers it, thank you!